# How to create an ObjectStore with compond key in IndexedDB with Dart

Tags: dart, indexeddb, dart-html

JavaScript can use

```dart
var objectStore = theDb.createObjectStore("store1", { keyPath: ["key1","key2"] });
```

to create ObjectStore **with compound key**.

But how to do this in dart?

Dart docs says:
ObjectStore createObjectStore(String name, {String keyPath, bool autoIncrement})

keyPath is a String, does dart support compound key?

Comment: I replaced my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this
(Works like in JavaScript https://gist.github.com/nolanlawson/8330172)

```dart
idb.ObjectStore objectStore = db.createObjectStore('persons', keyPath: 'name');

...

    var persons = [
                   {'name': ['complex', 'key']},
                   {'name': ['very complex', 'key', 1]},
                   {'name': ['very complex', 'key', 2]},
                   {'name': ['very complex', 'key', 3]},
                   {'name': ['very complex', 'key', 'foo']}
                   ];

...

objectStore.add(person).then((value) { ...
```